# How to add credit card using Braintree with 3D Secure verification and then transaction?

Tags: braintree, 3d-secure

As part of the flow, I have a separate step for adding a credit card. That means I'm creating credit cards via Braintree without running a transaction. For future transactions, vaulted credit cards can be used.

As I understand it right (correct me if I'm wrong), I can and should verify credit cards on their creation by running 3d Secure verification.

There are two things I'm not sure about:

1. Should I even run 3d Secure verification when adding a credit card?
2. After add card use this card of 3d Secure verification transation.

If I follow this step the verification popup is shown two times, First for add card and second for transation.

As I didn't find a clear answer in the Braintree doc and by googling. Can please verifing the step's is it write way?